# Cannot cancel uninstallation with InstallException

Tags: c#

I have a C# application that gets installed on the system. I need to prevent its uninstallation by checking a flag retrieved from a remote server. I used the `InstallException` method, but it does not stop the uninstallation instead shows a `Error 1001` dialog box and uninstalls the application. Following is the code I am using

```
protected override void OnBeforeUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.OnBeforeUninstall(savedState);

        //Get Flag value from remote server

        if (flag == 0)
        {
           throw new InstallException("Cannot Uninstall");
        }

    }
```

I am unable to cancel the uninstallation. Please help.